# Snowflake schema and table reference in User Defined Function arguments

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a User Defined Function (UDF) in Snowflake where the arguments can take in schema, table, and column values as variables so that the function can dynamically call different tables.  I tried to do this and save the function but Snowflake threw an error saying that the schema name did not exist - it tried to look for the schema using the argument name rather than the variable that will be entered into the function arguments.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DB_NAME"."SCHEMA_NAME"."FUNCTION_NAME"(
    SCHEMA_VAR VARCHAR,
    TABLE_VAR VARCHAR,
    COLUMN_VAR VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (RETURN_COL VARCHAR)
AS
$$
SELECT COLUMN_VAR FROM "DB_NAME".SCHEMA_VAR.TABLE_VAR
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is dynamic SQL which is only allowed from a [stored procedur](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html)e, not a function.

From normal SQL you can use a [TABLE LITERAL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html) to have dynamical named tables from the perspective of your code running the SQL, but then you can also just do string manipluation in your code, but this method makes it injection safe.

Comment: Can the stored procedure return back a table dataset?  I tried the table literal in the definition of the UDF and it was still erroring by interpreting the parameter name as the actual name of the object rather than a placeholder in the function definition for the variable.

Comment: yes, that is why I said "from normal sql" not "a TABLE LITERAL will work in a UDF"

Comment: Also why do you need to dynamical get some rows from a dynamic table? If this is driven from a Task, then the task should be running a procedure, that builds the actually SQL that does the work you want to use the results from. When if you are running the SQL from an external tool, it should build the SQL to be what it wants. IMHO. I get that often the argument "we want to hide complex from people X" but normally hiding complexity is a method for also hiding performance from everybody.

Comment: The goal is to be able to run this from within the database (Snowflake) itself; probably a lot of different ways to handle because all types of scenarios.  In this case, my thought is that it is simpler and administratively more efficient to maintain as much logic as possible within the database so that it can be accessible and consistent to as many external tools as possible and minimize the number of places where complex logic is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, even if what you're trying to achieve was doable using a `UDF`, it's an overkill. Consider below

```
set (table_name, column_name) = ('mydb.myschema.mytable', 'mycolumn');

select $column_name
from identifier($table_name);
```

Comment: Perhaps overkill but I'm trying to avoid re-writing the same set of SQL over and over because I want to loop over a set of tables and columns that I want to run inside this function.  My view is that using a function will improve efficiency because if I need to modify the query I just update the function.

Comment: @Declan Is the list of tables finite?

Comment: if by finite, you mean not infinite, then yes the list of tables will be finite at runtime, but the intent is that the list of tables can dynamically change over time so that is why the function is important.